# How to list all commits containing a file by name

Tags: git

I'd like to know all commits that are containing (not only changing) a specific file.

What I tried was:

```
git rev-list --all -- .gitmodules
git log --all --pretty="%H" -- .gitmodules
```

These commands are only displaying those commits that have modified a specific file. I'm also interested in those commits that contain the unmodified file in it's tree.

I want to use this to further analyse of those commits in order to create a submodule usage report.

Comment: How can a file be in a commit without being changed?

Comment: @HRK44 Every commit contains a pointer to a tree that points to all files that would be in the worktree if the commit is checked out. All files, modified or not. Of course git does its best to not waste disk space so it only stores pointers to non-modified files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is the creation of a script that lists the commits for each of the files in a directory:

```
# !/bin/bash 

for f in `ls -f` 
    do 

    # Var colors
    resaltBlue=$'\033[47m\033[2;34m'
    res=$'\033[0m'
    # Print the file where you will get your commits
    echo -e "$resaltBlue Archive : $f $res"
    # Print the commit in oneline
    git log --oneline "$f"
done
```

the output :

[image: Output]

***This script can be improved as desired by the user.***

Comment: Doesn't `git log --oneline "$f"` lead to the problem described by the OP: *"only displaying those commits that have modified a specific file"*? While the OP wants **all** commits that contain the file(s)…

Comment: As I did not understand @phd

Answer (score 0):

> These commands [`git log` and `git rev-list` when given a file name] are only displaying those commits that have modified a specific file. I'm also interested in those commits that contain the unmodified file in its tree.

In this case, you will want to write your own program, probably a shell script.

Start with `git rev-list` as it is the general-purpose plumbing program with which one writes Git scripts.  The output from `git rev-list`, as you have seen, is just one raw hash ID per line, by default.  These are the hash IDs of the commits that are:

- [*reachable from*](http://think-like-a-git.net/) the command line arguments, and
- *selected by* any constraints you included.  (A file name constrains the output to ordinary, non-merge commits in which the file contained in that commit differs from the file in that commit's parent—precisely what you *didn't* want.)

So `git rev-list --all` finds commits that are reachable from all references, and with no constraints, lists all of those hash IDs.  Now all you need do is retain commits in which the file exists, and discard commits in which it does not.  The easiest way to do this from a script is:

```
git rev-list --all | while read hash; do
    if git rev-parse --quiet --verify $hash:.gitmodules >/dev/null; then
        echo $hash # file .gitmodules exists in $hash
    # else
    #   file .gitmodules does not exist in $hash
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes looping through all existing commits will do the job, but also consumes some more analysis time, because I have many repositories with many commits to analyze. 
I was hoping that I can use the git internals to provide me this answer in a fast way.

Comment: You can write this in something other than shell script, and/or fancy it up using `git cat-file --batch-check`, but it's not going to be super-fast no matter how you do it.